# MVC area routing configuration issue

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a solution set up with the following structure

```
-Controllers
---HomeController
---SomeGeneralController

-Areas
---Admin
-----Controllers
-------AController
-------BController

---Settings
-----Controllers
-------CController
-------DController
```

I would like to set the routing so it follows these rules:

```
/anystringdoesntmatter/somegeneral/1
/lksjflkjs/somegeneral/index/1
/admin/somegeneral/index/1
/settings/somegeneral/index/1    // all these paths should route to to root 'somegeneralcontroller'
```

So basically, when any url has a controller of 'somegeneral', even if there is an area match, it will still route to the root 'somegeneralcontroller'

I am aware that route registration order matters as the first correct match is the one that is supplied. With that in mind, my routing is set as follows in global.asax.cs

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

//RouteConfig.cs

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{path}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, path = UrlParameter.Optional });


//AreaRegistration.cs

public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Any assistance would be very appreciated as I'm a bit stuck. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a "primary" route before any route registration like,

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SomeGeneral",
            url: "{path}/SomeGeneral/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "SomeGeneral", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});

//Then add the rest of the routes

AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

the first route should intercept the following urls:

```
/lksjflkjs/somegeneral/index/1
/admin/somegeneral/index/1
/settings/somegeneral/index/1
```

hope this helps